# Spring PropertyOverrideConfigurer not overriding PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer?

Tags: java, spring, properties, spring-4

I have a Spring 4.0 application in which I use a property placeholder for default bean values, and property-override for overriding in these values in production environment. The code looks like this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties" />
<context:property-override ignore-resource-not-found="true" ignore-unresolvable="true" location="file:${config.file}" />
```

So in the production enviroment, you pass the parameter -Dconfig.file=path/to/config/file.properties on Tomcat startup to override these values. Example:

Placeholder file:

```
dataSource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://10.46.1.1;database=TESTDB
dataSource.user=mvdb
dataSource.password=xxx
```

Production file:

```
dataSource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://10.77.10.14:1433;database=DB
dataSource.user=mvdb
dataSource.password=xxx
```

and the bean is defined as:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${dataSource.url}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${dataSource.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${dataSource.password}"/>    
    (more properties omitted)
</bean>
```

However, these values are not getting overridden with the overriden file! I can see in the startup that both files gets loaded:

```
[2015-07-14 10:37:57:057 CEST]  INFO  support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer: Loading properties file from class path resource [config.properties]
[2015-07-14 10:37:58:058 CEST]  INFO  config.PropertyOverrideConfigurer: Loading properties file from URL [file:C:/var/opt/config/config.properties]
```

But it still uses the values from the placeholder classpath file and tries to connect to the test database.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well of course it will. It will override properties not placeholders. The bean named `dataSource` doesn't have a `url` property it has a `jdbcUrl` property. But why on earth do you have this contraption? Why not simply externalize the property file into a well known location and load it from there. Modify it for each environment instead of trying to override things.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize the property had to have the exact same name. The property file is externalized, but we use a property file on the classpath for the dev environment.